# Redireccionar con método GET

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario, lo cual quiero que si esta todo OK, me haga `header('Location: ')` con un parámetro para recibir por método GET en el `index.php`. Funciona perfecto. Pero hay alguna forma de que cuando haga ese redireccionamiento, me ubique en donde esta el formulario situado? Para mostrar el parámetro enviado, que seria un `<p>` justo debajo del botón. El formulario lo tengo en un `tab-content` donde muestro la info, según el botón que elijan por secciones. Ósea que oculto una sección, si esta seleccionada otra.(espero explicarme bien).

muestro el código del formulario:

```
<!-- Tab Container 2 -->
                <input class="tab-radio" id="main-tab-2" name="main-group" type="radio"/>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="sub-tabs-container">
                    <label for="sub-tab2-1" class="sub-tab">NEUQUEN</label>
                    <label for="sub-tab2-2" class="sub-tab">MENDOZA</label>
                    </div>
                    <input class="tab-radio" id="sub-tab2-1" name="sub-group2" type="radio" checked="checked">
                    <div class="sub-tab-content">
                    <!-- FORMULARIO NEUQUEN-->
                        <h3 align="center">REGISTRO DE USUARIOS <span style="color:red; font-weight: bold">NEUQUEN</span></h3>
                        <table width="400" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="15" align="center" >
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <form  method="POST" action="../../Usuarios/carga_user.php">
                                            <table style="auto">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="td">
                                                        <input class="input_user" type='text' maxlength="15" name="usuario" value="" placeholder="USUARIO" required autocomplete='off' />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="td">
                                                        <select class="input_user" name="region" required>
                                                            <option value="" selected="selected"> - selecccionar region - </option>
                                                            <option value="*****">Dashboard - Administrador</option>
                                                            <option value="*****">NQN - GNOC</option>
                                                            <option value="******">NQN - RDLS</option>
                                                            <option value="*****">NQN - PH</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="td">
                                                        <select class="input_user" name="permisos" required>
                                                            <option value="" selected="selected" required> - selecccionar permiso - </option>
                                                            <option value="Administrador">Administrador</option>
                                                            <option value="Estandar">Estandar</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit_3">REGISTRAR</button>
                                            <?php 
                                                if(isset($_GET['param'])){
                                                    echo '<p id="param_get">'.$_GET['param'].'</p>';
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

En el archivo php `carga_user.php` tengo asi:

```
    if (!$stmt->error){
      header('Location: index.php?param=Registrado correctamente');
    }
```

Si me pudieran guiar, os agradeceré!

Answer (score 2):

Para ubicar la página en una posición determinada, mediante la URL, lo más fácil es usar un `#` y la id del elemento

Por ejemplo:
`index.php?param=Registrado%20correctamente#sub-tab2-1`

Siendo la Id del radio button

Para activar el `tab`, puedes usar la siguiente función

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  let url = new URL(location.href);
  document.querySelector(url.hash).checked=true;
  
  
  //El siguiente código tambien puede ser necesario
  //document.querySelector(url.hash + " + .tab-content").scrollIntoView();
});
```

Tu usas radio button para los tab, entonces usas el evento `DOMContentLoaded` para determinar cuando el DOM ha cargado, luego tomas la URL y sacas la parte que tiene el `#` que es la id del radio button y lo pones como cheheado.

Comment: Gracias por tu info, sabia de ponerle una ID en la url, pero no me funciona, y creo que es por que tengo oculto esa sección al refrescar la web. Tengo 3 secciones. y la sección del formulario, esta en la 2da oculta, y no accede a el, si no se aprieta el botón.

Comment: @MatiasTonnera Ok, ahora entiendo mejor. Tienes unos `Tabs`, estas usando una librería para esos tabs o son de creación propia?

Comment: creación propia

Comment: @MatiasTonnera Prueba el código que te he puesto

Comment: Probe el codigo, pero me tira este error:`` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollIntoView')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>`` No se como ponerlo en comentarios correctamente, disculpen

Comment: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': The provided selector is empty.

Comment: @MatiasTonnera Parece que el selector no era el correcto, pueba ahora (se cambia el `>` por un `+`)